# Convert large amount of code to data in IDA

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

Well, Unfortunately I hit 'C' on a data section of a binary i had worked a lot on and saved it as i had a lot of work unsaved. I tried converting this huge section back to data but whenever i select lines and press 'D', only the line where the cursor was gets converted to data.

So, My question is, How do i mark/convert a large amount of data to code in IDA (specifically 6.1)

(The target architecture is ARM if that matters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`D` is to define a single data. You can go to the first instruction and use `U` for `Undefine`. It will remove more code than "Convert to data".

Answer (score 7):

You could do it with a quick IDAPython script, e.g. enter:

```
for a in xrange(startaddr, endaddr): MakeCode(a)
```

into the 'Python' field of the Output window.